# Default radio button not working in second tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to put some radio buttons on a secondary window in tkinter, but I cannot correctly set the default button to be selected. The weird thing is, the code seems to work fine if I put the buttons on the root window, but not any other window.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def radiobtnwindow():
    window2 = Toplevel()

    y_n = StringVar()
    y_n.set('N')
    #y_n.set('Y')

    r1 = Radiobutton(window2, text='Yes', variable=y_n, value='Y').pack()
    r2 = Radiobutton(window2, text='No', variable=y_n, value='N').pack()

btn = Button(root, text='click', command=radiobtnwindow).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Please help!

Comment: Your `StringVar` is referenced only by a local variable, which disappears at the end of the function - leaving the `RadioButton`s with no place to store their state.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is fixed simply by putting the variables outside the function globalizing them from inside the function.

Like this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

y_n = StringVar()
y_n.set('N')
# y_n.set('Y')


def radiobtnwindow():
    global y_n

    window2 = Toplevel()

    r1 = Radiobutton(window2, text='Yes', variable=y_n, value='Y').pack()
    r2 = Radiobutton(window2, text='No', variable=y_n, value='N').pack()


btn = Button(root, text='click', command=radiobtnwindow).pack()

root.mainloop()
```